# Can you leave out "for" in "ask somebody their age"?

Tags: prepositions, ellipsis

Is the form "ask somebody their age" (as opposed to "ask somebody for their age") correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of these forms sound fine. The only difference is the second may sound a little more formal due to the use of the additional "for".

I cannot really think of a scenario when you would actually use this as a phrase beyond, "Is it okay to *ask somebody their age*".

I feel the question could do with some context and scenario.